# Execute Python script from apache as a root

Tags: python-2.7, apache2, firewall, mod-python, openbsd

I am using mod_python for executing a Python script from Apache 2.2.x at OpenBSD 5.1.
I am successfully running a Python script which does not require root privilege.
But I am executing several function of Firewall(Packet Filter) from Python Script which requires root privilege.
Will anyone tell me how can i do it please ??

Comment: You probably want to use `sudo` - very carefully. See [this link](http://linux-bsd-sharing.blogspot.com/2009/03/howto-using-sudo-on-freebsd.html). Note the warnings and instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722172/how-can-i-have-a-php-script-run-a-shell-script-as-root)!!

Comment: I am using mod_python for execution of python scripts . is it possible to execute specific python script from apache ???